kubernetes cronjob error: Saw a job that the controller did not create or forgot
Task:->  Restarting pod automatically at specific time.
cronjob not working fine after manually triger, getting error- like Saw a job that the controller did not create or forgot: vijay-deployment-restart-manual-a7s16



once manually triger cronjob , job will start for restarting pod but getting this errors -- Job has reached the specified backoff limitenter image description here enter image description here

current version :- based on this version
Client Version: v1.29.4
Kustomize Version: v5.0.4-0.20230601165947-6ce0bf390ce3
Server Version: v1.29.4-eks-036c24b

how to fix this.
kind: ServiceAccount
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: vijay-deployment-restart
  namespace: odex



apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: Vijay-deployment-restart
  namespace: odex`your text`
rules:
  - apiGroups: ["apps", "extensions"]
    resources: ["deployments"]
    resourceNames: ["odex-webapp-c88ae204"]
    verbs: ["get", "patch", "list", "watch"] # "list" and "watch" are only needed
                                             # if you want to use `rollout status`


apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: Vijay-deployment-restart
  namespace: odex
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: vijay-deployment-restart
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: vijay-deployment-restart
    namespace: odex

cronjob

apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
name: vijay-deployment-restart
namespace: od
spec:
concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
schedule: '48 10 * * *' # This will run daily at
jobTemplate:
spec:
backoffLimit: 3
activeDeadlineSeconds: 800
template:
spec:
serviceAccountName: vijay-deployment-restart
restartPolicy: Never
containers:
- name: kubectl
image: bitnami/kubectl:latest # Specify the version if needed
command:
- 'kubectl'
- 'rollout'
- 'restart'
- 'deployment/mango-deployment'

Logs
22m         Normal    Scheduled                pod/vijay-deployment-restart-manual-a7s16-6kfm4      Successfully assigned odex/vijay-deployment-restart-manual-a7s16-6kfm4 to ip-
10-1-255-31.ap-south-1.compute.internal
22m         Normal    Pulling                  pod/vijay-deployment-restart-manual-a7s16-6kfm4      Pulling image "bitnami/kubectl:latest"
22m         Normal    Pulled                   pod/vijay-deployment-restart-manual-a7s16-6kfm4      Successfully pulled image "bitnami/kubectl:latest" in 1.481434024s (1.4814430
65s including waiting)
22m         Normal    Created                  pod/vijay-deployment-restart-manual-a7s16-6kfm4      Created container kubectl
22m         Normal    Started                  pod/vijay-deployment-restart-manual-a7s16-6kfm4      Started container kubectl
25m         Normal    Scheduled                pod/vijay-deployment-restart-manual-a7s16-7b78g      Successfully assigned odex/vijay-deployment-restart-manual-a7s16-7b78g to ip-
10-1-255-31.ap-south-1.compute.internal
25m         Normal    Pulling                  pod/vijay-deployment-restart-manual-a7s16-7b78g      Pulling image "bitnami/kubectl:latest"
25m         Normal    Pulled                   pod/vijay-deployment-restart-manual-a7s16-7b78g      Successfully pulled image "bitnami/kubectl:latest" in 1.506635384s (1.5066520
44s including waiting)
25m         Normal    Created                  pod/vijay-deployment-restart-manual-a7s16-7b78g      Created container kubectl
25m         Normal    Started                  pod/vijay-deployment-restart-manual-a7s16-7b78g      Started container kubectl
26m         Normal    Scheduled                pod/vijay-deployment-restart-manual-a7s16-cnctx      Successfully assigned odex/vijay-deployment-restart-manual-a7s16-cnctx to ip-
10-1-255-31.ap-south-1.compute.internal
26m         Normal    Pulling                  pod/vijay-deployment-restart-manual-a7s16-cnctx      Pulling image "bitnami/kubectl:latest"
26m         Normal    Pulled                   pod/vijay-deployment-restart-manual-a7s16-cnctx      Successfully pulled image "bitnami/kubectl:latest" in 1.436445321s (1.4364548
92s including waiting)
26m         Normal    Created                  pod/vijay-deployment-restart-manual-a7s16-cnctx      Created container kubectl
26m         Normal    Started                  pod/vijay-deployment-restart-manual-a7s16-cnctx      Started container kubectl
27m         Normal    Scheduled                pod/vijay-deployment-restart-manual-a7s16-m98hb      Successfully assigned odex/vijay-deployment-restart-manual-a7s16-m98hb to ip-
10-1-255-31.ap-south-1.compute.internal
27m         Normal    Pulling                  pod/vijay-deployment-restart-manual-a7s16-m98hb      Pulling image "bitnami/kubectl:latest"
27m         Normal    Pulled                   pod/vijay-deployment-restart-manual-a7s16-m98hb      Successfully pulled image "bitnami/kubectl:latest" in 1.49095318s (1.49096263
s including waiting)
27m         Normal    Created                  pod/vijay-deployment-restart-manual-a7s16-m98hb      Created container kubectl
27m         Normal    Started                  pod/vijay-deployment-restart-manual-a7s16-m98hb      Started container kubectl
27m         Normal    Scheduled                pod/vijay-deployment-restart-manual-a7s16-twx82      Successfully assigned odex/vijay-deployment-restart-manual-a7s16-twx82 to ip-
10-1-255-31.ap-south-1.compute.internal
27m         Normal    Pulling                  pod/vijay-deployment-restart-manual-a7s16-twx82      Pulling image "bitnami/kubectl:latest"
27m         Normal    Pulled                   pod/vijay-deployment-restart-manual-a7s16-twx82      Successfully pulled image "bitnami/kubectl:latest" in 1.446334384s (1.4463481
54s including waiting)
27m         Normal    Created                  pod/vijay-deployment-restart-manual-a7s16-twx82      Created container kubectl
27m         Normal    Started                  pod/vijay-deployment-restart-manual-a7s16-twx82      Started container kubectl
27m         Normal    Scheduled                pod/vijay-deployment-restart-manual-a7s16-zr894      Successfully assigned odex/vijay-deployment-restart-manual-a7s16-zr894 to ip-
10-1-255-31.ap-south-1.compute.internal
27m         Normal    Pulling                  pod/vijay-deployment-restart-manual-a7s16-zr894      Pulling image "bitnami/kubectl:latest"
27m         Normal    Pulled                   pod/vijay-deployment-restart-manual-a7s16-zr894      Successfully pulled image "bitnami/kubectl:latest" in 1.547233824s (1.5472634
65s including waiting)
27m         Normal    Created                  pod/vijay-deployment-restart-manual-a7s16-zr894      Created container kubectl
27m         Normal    Started                  pod/vijay-deployment-restart-manual-a7s16-zr894      Started container kubectl
27m         Normal    SuccessfulCreate         job/vijay-deployment-restart-manual-a7s16            Created pod: vijay-deployment-restart-manual-a7s16-zr894
27m         Normal    SuccessfulCreate         job/vijay-deployment-restart-manual-a7s16            Created pod: vijay-deployment-restart-manual-a7s16-twx82
27m         Normal    SuccessfulCreate         job/vijay-deployment-restart-manual-a7s16            Created pod: vijay-deployment-restart-manual-a7s16-m98hb
26m         Normal    SuccessfulCreate         job/vijay-deployment-restart-manual-a7s16            Created pod: vijay-deployment-restart-manual-a7s16-cnctx
25m         Normal    SuccessfulCreate         job/vijay-deployment-restart-manual-a7s16            Created pod: vijay-deployment-restart-manual-a7s16-7b78g
22m         Normal    SuccessfulCreate         job/vijay-deployment-restart-manual-a7s16            Created pod: vijay-deployment-restart-manual-a7s16-6kfm4
22m         Warning   BackoffLimitExceeded     job/vijay-deployment-restart-manual-a7s16            Job has reached the specified backoff limit
22m         Warning   UnexpectedJob            cronjob/vijay-deployment-restart                     Saw a job that the controller did not create or forgot: vijay-deployment-rest
art-manual-a7s16
PS C:\Users\Vijay.kumar\k8 yaml file>

how to fix this issue.
